# Inbuilt Laptop Camera Crashing

Tags: lenovo, webcam, camera

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a Lenovo IdeaPad S340. When I try to run something that uses the camera (like Zoom or Skype), the indicator light flashes for a split second. Most of the time I get no image at all, but sometimes I get a partial ghost image that lingers for up to maybe ten seconds before going entirely black.
I noticed this issue today after not using the webcam for a couple of weeks.

Cheese simply shows black until I go to Preferences->Integrated Camera, at which point it freezes and needs to be force quit.
guvcview opens with a command line notice:

```
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.7
GUVCVIEW: couldn't open /home/logan/.config/guvcview2/video0 for read: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
GUVCVIEW (1): Guvcview error
     no video device (/dev/video0) found
```

ls /dev lists video8 and video9, and when I attempt to point guvcviewer to those spots with -d it gives the repeated command line error

```
V4L2_CORE: (VIDIOC_DQBUF) Unable to dequeue buffer: No such device
```

lsusb outputs

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 04f2:b61e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
```

I'm not sure what to make of any of this and the behavior doesn't seem to match any error reports I've found online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: per request, the relevant output from inxi -Fxz

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-6:17
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (ICL GT1)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3 direct render: Yes
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you open a terminal and enter `inxi -Fxz` and edit the output into your question? If you don't have inxi installed you can install it with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install inxi`